# Can't get results from esri request with flex

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, arcgis, esri

I am sending a request to get postal codes but it automatically adds to the sent URL:

```
geometry = {"ymin":-56716.2749875736,"xmax":91877.30799873594,"ymax":56716.2749875736,"xmin":-91877.30799873966}
```

And when I remove that above text from URL then it gets the correct result.

**Question** : I want to know how to remove it from the code as I didn't add it anywhere

My code:

```
mainUIComponent.promisingLocationsMap.zipCodeLayer.definitionExpression=buildMapQuery(false);
mainUIComponent.promisingLocationsMap.zipCodeLayer.url="https://services.arcgis.com/zmLUiqh7X11gGV2d/arcgis/rest/services/Canada_FSA_2014/FeatureServer/0";
```

What it is sending:

```
https://services.arcgis.com/zmLUiqh7X11gGV2d/arcgis/rest/services/Canada_FSA_2014/FeatureServer/0/query?returnGeometry=true&outSR=102100&where=CFSAUID IN ('G9A' )&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&inSR=102100&returnDistinctValues=false&f=json&geometry={"ymin":-56716.2749875736,"xmax":91877.30799873594,"ymax":56716.2749875736,"xmin":-91877.30799873966}
```

What it should send:

```
https://services.arcgis.com/zmLUiqh7X11gGV2d/arcgis/rest/services/Canada_FSA_2014/FeatureServer/0/query?returnGeometry=true&outSR=102100&where=CFSAUID IN ('G9A' )&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&inSR=102100&returnDistinctValues=false&f=json
```

Comment: (1) When you check [**this page**](https://services.arcgis.com/zmLUiqh7X11gGV2d/arcgis/rest/services/Canada_FSA_2014/FeatureServer/0) (your code's `zipCodeLayer.url`) does it show you the **exact same** numbers again (for `xMax`, `yMax`, etc)?...

Comment: (2) Also regarding that [**What it should send**](https://services.arcgis.com/zmLUiqh7X11gGV2d/arcgis/rest/services/Canada_FSA_2014/FeatureServer/0/query?returnGeometry=true&outSR=102100&where=CFSAUID%20IN%20(%27G9A%27%20)&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&inSR=102100&returnDistinctValues=false&f=json) gives you JSON text. Is it not enough to just load the link into AS3 as a String var then parse with JSON decoder?